# Jboss startup very slow on Windows Server

Tags: java, solr, jboss

I'm using Jboss(WildFly 9) to host my Solr application on a Windows Server(2012), but if I start JBoss it's very slow and taking at least 15 mins to start. There is only one app (solr.war).

The same JBoss in my local with the same WAR takes less than a minute to start.

The JVM is set as MIN 4GB and Max 16GB on the servers.

What could be the reason it is very slow?

Comment: Thousands of reasons, many of which have nothing to do with JBoss or Java and everything to do with the server. With absolutely no investigation from you, there is no hope to provide any kind of answer.

Comment: try to start server without your war file and see logs and timing, then put your war file again you check logs, now you may find any problem with your war.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the sever without war and if it takes normal time in bootup then check the war code else check the jboss version and logs.